# How to parse in nested json array in ListView.Builder in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart

I'm calling an api which returns a nested json array list and when i try to display an `id` of `table_photos` inside `listview.builder` then it is displaying only `id:1`. I want to display all three id's which is `id:1,id:11,id:12` inside `listview.builder`. Below is the sample json along with the code and `MainPage.dart` i'm displaying only short code due to the long file

> JSON

```
{
    "message": "Tables returend",
    "tables": [
        {
        "id": "7"
        "table_photos": [
            {
                "id": "7"
            }
        ]
    },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "table_photos": [
                {
                    "id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11"
                },
                {
                    "id": "12"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Model

```
class TableGenerateTablesTablePhotos {

  String? id;

  TableGenerateTablesTablePhotos({
    this.id,
  });
  TableGenerateTablesTablePhotos.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    return data;
  }
}

class TableGenerateTables {

  String? id;
  List<TableGenerateTablesTablePhotos?>? tablePhotos;

  TableGenerateTables({
    this.id,
    this.tablePhotos,
  });
  TableGenerateTables.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
  if (json["table_photos"] != null) {
  final v = json["table_photos"];
  final arr0 = <TableGenerateTablesTablePhotos>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(TableGenerateTablesTablePhotos.fromJson(v));
  });
    tablePhotos = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    if (tablePhotos != null) {
      final v = tablePhotos;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["table_photos"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class TableGenerate {

  String? message;
  List<TableGenerateTables?>? tables;

  TableGenerate({
    this.message,
    this.tables,
  });
  TableGenerate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json["message"]?.toString();
  if (json["tables"] != null) {
  final v = json["tables"];
  final arr0 = <TableGenerateTables>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(TableGenerateTables.fromJson(v));
  });
    tables = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["message"] = message;
    if (tables != null) {
      final v = tables;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["tables"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

> Repository

```
class Repository{
  Future<List< TableGenerateTables >?> makeRequestTables(int id, int count) async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('API_URL'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List< TableGenerateTables >? tables =
          TableGenerate.fromJson(data).tables as List< TableGenerateTables >;
      return tables;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

> MainPage.dart

```
  Widget showTable(List<TablesTables> data) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(data[index].tablePhotos![index]!.id!), //It is displaying "1"
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: You are using data.length in the list view. that's why it is showing only one data according to your pasted json. to make it work you need one more nested listview which accepts data[index].tablePhotos.length as itemCount.

Comment: @MEETPrajapati yes now i have added another nested listview.builder but this time it is showing an error "Invalid value:Not in inclusive range 0...1: 2". By the way i have updated the `json` data array. `ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data[index].tablePhotos!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text(data[index].tablePhotos![index]!.id!);
                  })`

Comment: change the name of  "int index" in the nested list because in return Text(data[index].tablePhotos![index]!.id!);  the data object is using that nested index which it should not.

Comment: I am glad to hear that!